# Differentiability inequality function $f: U \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ be an open set and $f: U \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ differentiable at  $a\in U $. Prove there exist $\epsilon>0$ and $M>0$ such that if $\left \| h \right \|<\epsilon$ then $a+h \in U$ and $\left | f(a+h)-f(a) \right |\leq M\left \| h \right \|$.

Attempt: Since $U$ is open there exist $\epsilon>0$ such that $B(a;\epsilon)\subseteq U$. Choose $h \in \mathbb{R}^m$ such that if $\left \| h \right \|<\epsilon$ then $a+h \in B(a;\epsilon) \subseteq U$. Since $f: U \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ differentiable at $a$, then

$$
|f(a+h)-f(a)|=|f'(a)h+r(h)| 
$$
where $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{r(h)}{||h||}=0$.

But $|f'(a)h+r(h)| \leq |f'(a)h|+|r(h)|$. Is this correct?

Also i dont know if I can simply use $|f'(a)h|=|f'(a)|||h||$.

Comment: Yes. This is correct. Also, $|r(h)|\le \|h\|$ for $\|h\|$ small enough. BTW, you should write $\|f'(a)\|$ since the gradient is a vector. For small $\|h\|$ your quantity is bounded by $\|f'(a)\|+1$ (say). The reason why $a+h\in U$ for small $h$ is the openness of the set.

Comment: Ah yes, I can use that $r(h)$ is less or equal than $||h||$ (because of the limit), thank you.